# how to get Current index in stack using C#

Tags: c#

I have inserted values into Stack in C# . I need values of mystack[0], mystack[1]. How to do it. I have tried methods in stack but please give me hint of code i will try it

Comment: FYI, the language is named "C#" not "CSharp"

Answer (score 4):

You can use `ElementAt()` for this.

```
Stack<Int32> foo = new Stack<Int32>();
foo.Push(5); //element 1
foo.Push(1); //element 0
int val = foo.ElementAt(1); //This is 5
```

Since stacks are last on first out, if you want to get the first item you added to the stack, you can use:

```
int val = foo.ElementAt(foo.Count - 1);
```

Keep in mind, `ElementAt` is a LINQ extension method that will enumerate the stack as an array and return the desired index.  For large stacks, or where performance is critical, you might want to consider using another data structure such as `List<T>`.

Comment: That is leveraging the LINQ extension method on IEnumerable.  The OP should be made aware of the gymnastics going on there to make that happen.

Comment: thnkx u so Mike it was very helpful

Answer (score 2):

If you need the items by index, perhaps a `List<T>` would be a more appropriate data structure?

A stack is intended to only allow you to get the most recently inserted item.  There are ways to bypass that behavior, but surely if you need the items by index this works better:

```
var myList = new List<Int32>();
myList.Add(100);
myList.Add(200);
myList.Add(300);
myList.Add(400);
Console.Out.WriteLine(myList[2]); // Prints "300"
```

Comment: other than a list is there any methos called as stack.getindex[0] or any other

Comment: Not in the built-in stack.  You need to convert it to an array or list to do that.  There are built-in methods to do so- `myStack.toArray()` or the LINQ `ToList()` extension method.